# Catch The remote host closed the connection c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, ashx

I'm having problem catching the error

> The remote host closed the connection

on the production server but it is working on my local machine. My code is like this

```
try
{
    SqlDataSource_Gift.saveGiftDownloadLogs(guestGuid, guestEmail, couponCode, albumId, trackId, "Downloading");
    List<faeTrackInfoDetail> result = SqlDataSource_Track.getTrackInfoDetail(trackId);
            faeTrackInfoDetail item = result.First();
    catalogueId = item.CatalogueID;
    filename = item.DiscNo.ToString() + "." + item.TrackNo.ToString() + " - " + CleanFileName(item.TrackTitle) + "." + mediaType;
    urlPath = "mydomain.com/Download/DownloadAudioTrack.ashx?id=" + catalogueId + "&trackid=" + trackId + "&ext=" + mediaType;
    context.Response.ClearContent();
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    if (mediaType != "mp3")
    {
       context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    else
    {
       context.Response.ContentType = "application/mpeg";
    }
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + (char)(34) + filename + (char)(34));
    context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        using (var download = wc.OpenRead(urlPath))
        {
            using (var respStream = context.Response.OutputStream)
            {
                download.CopyTo(respStream);

                SqlDataSource_Gift.saveGiftDownloadLogs(guestGuid, guestEmail, couponCode, albumId, trackId, "Downloaded");
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string exceptionMessage = ex.Message;
    if (exceptionMessage.ToLower().Contains("the remote host closed the connection."))
    {
        // Download Cancelled!
        SqlDataSource_Gift.saveGiftDownloadLogs(guestGuid, guestEmail, couponCode, albumId, trackId, "Cancelled");
    }
    else
    {
        // Download Error!
        SqlDataSource_Gift.saveGiftDownloadLogs(guestGuid, guestEmail, couponCode, albumId, trackId, "Error");
    }
}
```

I need to know when the user cancelled the downloading and log it to the database. Right now it is not working when the code is deployed to prod server but working when I'm debugging.

Is there a settings in `IIS` that I need to check. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use IISExpress or an real IIS instance on local?

Comment: By any chance on the production server, there is another framework installed then the english one? Never ever make decisions on localized strings.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I'm running it on IISExpress.

Comment: It is also working on IIS on my local.

Comment: I'm not sure the setup in production server.

Comment: I'm sure the framework is in English.

Comment: What do you mean with not working exactly?

Comment: When I run the application from VS.Net, the error "remote host closed the connection" is triggered when I cancelled the downloading process. But the not triggered in the production server.

Comment: Error r Exception r action is not happening? @user7450413

Comment: I've also tried deploying the site to my local IIS and the error is triggered. So it is working.

Comment: Yes @Sreemat. It is not happening in prod server.